# Is that possible to get a list of all cards for an organisation, by boards?

Tags: trello

As a team manager and having several projects, I would like to have a list of all cards, across all boards. Ideally, I would able to sort it by people or by due date.

I like Trello very much, but it is not easy to prepare a meeting using some printed documents, with it.